# Copy partition definitions from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have a table USERS with columns USER_ID and NAME, that is partitioned on the USER_ID column.

Say, I want to create another table USER_PHN with columns USER_ID and PHN_NO. This table should have the same partitions on USER_ID as in the USERS table. Is it possible to copy partition definitions from the original table into the new table?

Comment: SQL is just the structured query language - but the features you're asking about are most likely product-specific - so we need to know **what database** (and which version of it) you're using. IBM DB2? Informix? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Firebird? Or which other.....

Comment: What kind of partition is that? List? Hash? Range? Anything other than hash doesn't make sense for a column that sounds like the PK (user_id). Why do you think you need the same partitioning scheme for a child table? The partitioning scheme depends **heavily** on the queries that you run against the tables.

Comment: Why is this question "off topic"?

Answer (score 1):

If users and user_phn have a referential constraint, you can use reference partitioning, if you happen to be using Oracle 11g. See [Oracle® Database VLDB and Partitioning Guide 11g Release 1 (11.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#CACIHDII) for docu.

One of the advantages here is that you have less redundant data because to partitioning key does not need a copy in the child rows. That is already defined in the FK relation.

The child table inherits the partitioning definitions from the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

Consider scripting the USERS table in a procedure, finding the partition portion in the DDL and replace the table name with USER_PHN and then executing it.